# Return results from multiple list choice in Applescript

Tags: applescript

This script is for use in Capture One where I am assigning people's names to the EXIF data.

I am trying to return the results of a list that could be one or more choices made by the user. I can get it to work with using item 1 in the list but I can't figure out how to deal with someone choosing 2 or more names from anywhere in the list?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
tell application "Capture One 11"
set peopleChoices to {"Abbie", "Charlie", "De-Arne", "Dean", "Jason", "Marlene", "Peta ", "Phoenix", "Rod", "Vanessa", "Yvonne"}
set peopleList to choose from list peopleChoices with prompt "Select your keyword/s:" with multiple selections allowed
if the result is not false then
set exif_keywords to item 1 of the result
end if
set selectedVariants to get selected variants
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in selectedVariants
    set this_item to item i of selectedVariants
    set theID to id of (parent image of this_item)
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -Subject='" & exif_keywords & "' -m -overwrite_original_in_place " & quoted form of theID
    reload metadata this_item
end repeat
display dialog "EXIF data has been updated"
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constraining the list to one item in this line

```
set exif_keywords to item 1 of the result
```

Just change it to

```
set exif_keywords to result
```

I don't know how the keywords are supposed to be passed in the `exiftool` line, you might flatten the list with `text item delimiters`, this example joins the list comma separated. Replace `","` with `space` if the parameters have to be space separated.

```
set {ASTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ","}
set exif_keywords to exif_keywords as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASTID
```

Comment: Thanks very much - that works for the first part perfectly. I get the results back now but with no whitespace between each list item, which from searching around seems to be causing the issue with the next part.

For example: exif_keywords comes back as "CharlieJason", so TID doesn't know where to split it and I get this error.

Can’t get text item delimiters." number -1728 from text item delimiters

Comment: I found the answer - use "AppleScript's text item delimiters" instead of "text item delimiters" works perfectly. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Right, I overlooked the application tell block where `text item delimiters` must be referenced by adding `AppleScript's`

Answer (score 0):

I have included the whole working script below in case anyone else is looking for something similar. The "-sep" is part of exiftool and splits the string depending on what you put after it. I had to escape it for the shell script line but it nromally does not have the back slashes.

```
tell application "Capture One 11"
    set peopleChoices to {"Abbie", "Charlie", "De-Arne", "Dean", "Jason", "Marlene", "Peta", "Phoenix", "Rod", "Vanessa", "Yvonne"}
    set peopleList to choose from list peopleChoices with prompt "Select your keyword:" with multiple selections allowed
    if the result is not false then
        set exif_keywords to result
        set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ","}
        set exif_keywords to exif_keywords as text
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    end if
    set selectedVariants to get selected variants
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in selectedVariants
        set this_item to item i of selectedVariants
        set theID to id of (parent image of this_item)
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -sep \",\" -Keywords='" & exif_keywords & "' -m -overwrite_original_in_place " & quoted form of theID
        reload metadata this_item
    end repeat
    display dialog "EXIF data has been updated"
end tell
```